# Not able to get PDF file data response in axios call - Syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, axios

I have to preview PDF file in my react app.

I have axios get call. In this call getting Syntax error

**Here is my iframe call**

[image]

```
previewPDF = (attachment)=>{

    const config = { responseType: 'arraybuffer'
                    , responseEncoding: 'binary' 
                    , headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                ,'Accept': 'application/pdf'
                               } 
                   };

    const url = Navigation.transactionalApiPath + apiUrls.attachmentsGetFile + '/' + attachment.Id + '/true';
      axios.get(url,config)
       .then(response => {                    
       console.log('blob - response ',response);
      })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

**Here is header**

[image]

**Here is a Preview - Preview and Response tab are same**

[image]

**But I am getting Syntax error in console**

[image]

**Please help me to get response so I can display in iframe**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try this. I think other config was redundant and only `responseType: arraybuffer` would do the job.

Also, you need to convert the arraybuffer to blob and then to the url because iframe expects a string.

```js
previewPDF = (attachment)=>{

    const config = { responseType: 'arraybuffer' };

    const url = Navigation.transactionalApiPath + apiUrls.attachmentsGetFile + '/' + attachment.Id + '/true';
    
    axios.get(url,config)
     .then(response => {                    
       console.log('blob - response ',response);
       
       const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
       const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       return url;
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

```html
<iframe src={this.previewPDF(attachment)}
```

Comment: I tried. But issue is , its not coming in success Response . Its directly throw error and go to catch block